# Python: Unpacking dictionary with integer keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, integer, string-formatting, unpack

For a dictionary as follows:

```
my_dict={'name':'Stack', 'age':11}
print('Name is {name} and age is {age}.'.format(**my_dict))
#output# Name is Stack and age is 11
```

However, **if keys are integers in a dictionary**, how should I unpack the dictionary, for example:

```
new_dict={1:'Stack', 2:'over', 3:'flow'}
print('1 is {1} and 2 is {2} and 3 is {3}'.format(**new_dict))
#output error# tuple index out of range
```

In this case, how can I get result as follows:

```
1 is Stack and 2 is over and 3 is flow
```

I know one can do it with many other ways, but is it possible to use the same strategy in the first example. Thank you.

Comment: Numbers are used for positional indices. I.e. you could (but probably shouldn't) do `print('1 is {0} and 2 is {1} and 3 is {2}'.format(*new_dict))` or preferably `print(f'1 is {new_dict[1]} and 2 is {new_dict[2]} and 3 is {new_dict[3]}')
`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that unpacking. What you need is something else.

`**` in a function call unpacks a dict into keyword arguments, and keyword argument names are always strings. An int `1` isn't a valid keyword argument name. Even if it was, or if you converted the dict keys to strings, `str.format` wouldn't look for such a keyword argument.

`{1}`, `{2}`, etc. in `format` look for positional arguments, not keyword arguments. No `**` unpacking will produce positional arguments. Also, since they're positional, if you start at 1, you would need to have a dummy argument in position 0 so the rest of the arguments can go in the right positions.

If you really want to do this with a dict and a format string that looks like that, probably the easiest route would be to go through a [`string.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) subclass and override [`get_value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.get_value):

```
import string

class IntDictFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def get_value(self, key, args, kwargs):
        return kwargs[key]

format_string = '1 is {1} and 2 is {2} and 3 is {3}'

value_dict = {1:'Stack', 2:'over', 3:'flow'}

print(IntDictFormatter().vformat(format_string, (), value_dict))
```

Comment: Well, below is the code that does this. What's the problem?

Comment: @ShivamJha: Are you talking about your answer? Your answer doesn't do the unpacking either. It also doesn't generalize to other format strings, and `if k == list(my_dict.keys())[-1]` is really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.values()`, and only use one `*`:

```
new_dict={1:'Stack', 2:'over', 3:'flow'}

print('1 is {} and 2 is {} and 3 is {}'.format(*new_dict.values()))
```

Output:

```
1 is Stack and 2 is over and 3 is flow
```

The reason you get an error is because, you know that in f-strings, the things in the curly braces are evaluated during runtime.

And so, having numbers as keys will make python think the keys are regular integers.

UPDATE:

```
new_dict={1:'Stack', 2:'over', 3:'flow'}

print(f'3 is {new_dict[3]} and 1 is {new_dict[1]} and 2 is {new_dict[2]}')
```

Output:

```
3 is flow and 1 is Stack and 2 is over
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if I want result as "1 is stack and 3 in flow", means not list all elements or change the order like "3 is flow , 1 is stack , 2 is over"

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict={'name':'Stack', 'age':11, 1:'Stack', 2:'over', 3:'flow'}

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if k == list(my_dict.keys())[-1]:
        print(k, 'is', v)
    else:
        print(k, 'is', v, 'and ', end='')
```

it outputs:

```
name is Stack and age is 11 and 1 is Stack and 2 is over and 3 is flow
```